# Given the r.v. $\mathbb E(X \mid \mathcal D)(\omega)$, how do I find the conditional expectation w.r.t. an event $D \in \mathcal D$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Given a conditional expectation random variable $\mathbb E(X \mid \mathcal D)(\omega)$, how do I find the conditional expectation $X$ w.r.t. an event $D \in \mathcal D$? I'm not sure when we can evaluate $\mathbb E(X \mid \mathcal D)(\omega)$ at some special $\omega_0$ to yield some sort of explicit number, and when we have to do something different.

For example, in the example where $X$ is an r.v. taking on values $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ each with probability $1/6$ (e.g. a dice roll), then $\mathbb E(X\mid X \text{ is odd}) = 3$ and $\mathbb E(X\mid X \text{ is even}) = 4$. So now taking $\mathcal D$ to be the sigma-algebra $\{\varnothing, X^{-1}(\{1,3,5\}), X^{-1}(\{2,4,6\}), \Omega\}$, we get that $\mathbb E(X\mid\mathcal D)$ evaluated at any $\omega \in X^{-1}(\{1,3,5\})$ yields $3$, and for any $\omega \in X^{-1}(\{2,4,6\})$ yields $4$. However, this is a simple example with no guarantee that every time I want to find explicitly $\mathbb E(X\mid D)$ I just choose some $\omega \in D$ to evaluate $\mathbb E(X\mid\mathcal D)$ on.

Would it be $\mathbb E[\mathbb E(X\mid\mathcal D) \cdot 1_D]$? If so, wouldn't that be equal to $\mathbb E[X \cdot 1_D]$ by the definition of conditional expectation w.r.t a sigma-algebra? If that were so, what's the point of going to all the trouble of defining $\mathbb E(X\mid\mathcal D)(\omega)$ if we were just going to use $\mathbb E[X \cdot 1_D]$?

Comment: By definition, $E(E(X|D)1_A) = E(X1_A)$ for $A \in D.$

Comment: $E(X|D)$ is some sort of projection (it is in fact a projection from $L^2(\Omega, F)$ to $L^2(\Omega, D)$).

Comment: @WillM. I know that, but how does it help me explicitly calculate the conditional expectation with any arbitrary event in the sigma algebra?

Comment: No, $E(X|D)$ is for all intents and purposes a theoretical object.

Answer (score 1):

By definition [Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event),
 the conditional expectation of $X$ given the event $A$ is
$$E(X\mid A)=\frac{E(X1_A)}{P(A)}$$

For example

$$E(X\mid X \text{ is even})=\frac{E(X1_{ \{2,4,6\} })}{P(\{2,4,6\})}
=\frac{\frac{1}{6}(2+4+6)}{\frac{3}{6}}=\frac{12}{3}=4$$

Relation with sigma field:
lets $\sigma=\sigma\left(\{A, A^c \} \right)=\{\emptyset ,\Omega , A, A^c \}$

$$E(X|\sigma)=E(X|A)1_A + E(X|A^c)1_{A^c}$$

if you know $E(X|\sigma)(\omega)$ you know $E(X|1_A)$ since if 
$\omega\in A$
$$E(X|\sigma)(\omega)=E(X|A)$$

A little more general let $\sigma=\sigma\left(\{A_1,\cdots, A_n \} \right)=\{\emptyset ,\Omega , all \ A_i, all A_i\cup A_j ,\cdots, \}$

Where $A_i$ are disjoint and are a partition of $\Omega$.

In this case

$E(X|\sigma)=E(X|A_1)1_{A_1}+E(X|A_2)1_{A_2}+\cdots+E(X|A_n)1_{A_n}$

For Example $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $A_1=\{1,2 \}$ ,$A_2=\{3,4 \}$, and 
$A_3=\{5,6 \}$. Similarly If you know $E(X|\sigma)$ you already know $E(X|A_j)$. So you can calculate any $E(X|D)$ where $D\in \sigma$ like $$E(X|A_1\cup A_3)=\frac{E(X1_{A_1\cup A_3})}{P(A_1\cup A_3)}=\frac{E(X1_{A_1})+E(X1_{A_3})}{P(A_1)+ P(A_3)}
=\frac{E(X|A_1)P(A_1)+E(X|A_3)P(A_3)}{P(A_1)+ P(A_3)}$$

since you know all $E(X|A_i)$.

In general case, By definition of $E(X|\sigma)$, for all $D\in \sigma$
$$E(X1_D)=E( E(X|\sigma)1_D).$$

So if $P(D)> 0$

$$E(X|D)=\frac{E(X1_D)}{P(D)}=\frac{E( E(X|\sigma)1_D)}{P(D)}$$

If we come back to $E(X|A_1\cup A_3)$ so

$$E(X|A_1\cup A_3)=\frac{E( E(X|\sigma)1_D)}{P(D)}$$
$$=\frac{E( E(X|A_1)1_{A_1}(\omega) + E(X|A_3)1_{A_3}(\omega))}{P(A_1 \cup A_3)}=\frac{E(X|A_1)P(A_1)+E(X|A_3)P(A_3)}{P(A_1 \cup A_3)}$$ that is same with previous.

Comment: Your addendum is the fact I noticed and wrote out in my question. My question is what if the problem is more complicated, and we can't just evaluate the function at some point in the desired event that we want to find the conditional expectation on.

Comment: In here math.stackexchange.com/questions/3612150/… based on definition of $E(X|\sigma(Y))$, calculate $E(X|Y=y)$ for continues variable. In this situation $P(A)=P(Y=y)=0$ and $\sigma(Y)=Borel(R)$